# width: auto property not being respected with position: relative

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm currently trying to style a dropdown menu, but I'm running into some issues. The biggest one is that the dropdown elements don't seem to be exceed the size of their parent object when the css for the dropdown is set to relative.

[image]

(Had to block out the search results, sorry).

It seems to work on fixed, but only in Firefox, Chrome's dropdowns are all off.

[image]

So I think I need one of two solutions:

1. Fixing the width issue and keeping the position: relative
2. Fixing the offset issue that occurs ONLY in chrome, and setting the position: fixed attribute.

HTML:

```
<div id="node">
        <div id="nodebar">
            <input type="text" id="nodetext" placeholder="Enter a node" name="nodetext" value="">
            <div id="img-container">
                <img src="styles/magnifyingglass.png" id="img" alt="" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="nodebr"></div>
        <div id="noderesults">
            <div id="nodetruncated"><span class="truncated">Truncated search results..</span></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
#searchresults, #noderesults, #roadmapresults, #intersectnoderesults {
    max-width: 1000px;
    background: #2E3C3F;
    width:auto;
    height: 0px;
    padding: 0;
    border: none;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 3; /*So that the dropdown stays infront of the forms*/
}
```

Would anyone know how I could go about fixing this?

Comment: Post your code please or recreate a simplified version of the issue on http://jsfiddle.net or did you expect people to paste an image of the solution

Comment: Sorry I was updating the OP with the code as I accidentally submitted it. Its there now.

Comment: @Jake can you recreate the issue in fiddle? The code above doesn't really demonstrate the issue

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot as it relies on a couple of backend servlets to populate the dropdown data. I just thought this might be a simple issue of oversight on my part and thought I might as well put it up on stack overflow while wrestling with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up just fixing this by breaking down the CSS into one category for each one of the fields, set the position property to fixed, and scaled the css "top" property so that the results would fit for each of the search fields.